# How can I format a string to UUID format that contains hyphens

Tags: python, uuid

I have a string that looks like this. It's a UUID without the hyphens:

```
'0613ff4c000c0e08dda69667dc7d6c5b'
```

How can I format this string to look like a typical UUID with hyphens like the following:

```
'0613ff4c-000c-0e08-dda6-9667dc7d6c5b'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [the uuid module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html) from the standard library:

```
import uuid

original = '0613ff4c000c0e08dda69667dc7d6c5b'

str(uuid.UUID(original))
# '0613ff4c-000c-0e08-dda6-9667dc7d6c5b'
```