# How to Create UUID with dashes, instead of without dashes using uuid-package for Python 3.6?

Tags: python, uuid

I am using python v3.6, in Odoo framework.

I wanted to generate uuid, so I am using uuid as follows:

```
:~$ python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import uuid
>>> id =  uuid.uuid1().hex
>>> id
'daf59b684d6a11xz9a9c34028611c679'
>>>
```

How can I get uuid? separated by hyphens and dividing string into four parts as :
`daf59b684-d6a11x-z9a9c3402-8611c679`

I tried finding it on SO, but didn't get, instead got a reverse-one, opposite of my requirements as [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986712/creating-a-uuid-from-a-string-with-no-dashes).

how to create hyphens in betweens uuid-string, like this??

UUID-Docs [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html).

Comment: Related: [How can I format a string to UUID format that contains hyphens](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55420773/7851470)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just want to convert the `UUID` into a string:

```
>>> import uuid
>>> print(uuid.uuid1())
74ba3af4-4d6d-11ea-989f-784f435149ee
>>> u = str(uuid.uuid1())
>>> u
'7d7b626c-4d6d-11ea-989f-784f435149ee'
```

Note that this is [clearly documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.UUID):

> `str(uuid)` returns a string in the form `12345678-1234-5678-1234-567812345678` where the 32 hexadecimal digits represent the UUID.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you have a misconception about UUIDs. Those are just numbers, 128 binary digits is their inherent representation. The `hex` property just provides those as string formatted as hexadecimal. If you want the dashes in there, you can add them yourself easily, since you have the guarantee that you have 32 hexadecimal digits.

However, just read `help(uuid)`, because there's an even easier way to get what you want. Just convert the object to a string using `str(id)`.

Comment: Thanks @Ulrich for explanation for `hex` property, used for formatting as hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0):

str(uuid) will work, but watch out if uuid:UUID|None
str(None) == 'None'
so best use str(uuid) if uuid else None